# Getting digits of number in c#

Tags: c#, numbers, digits

I want to be able to take any digit from a number in C# , so I created a function to do so. I used only maths to get to the digit. Here is my code

```
static int GetDigit(int number, int k)
    {
        // k is the positiong of the digit I want to get from the number
        // I want to divide integer number to 10....0 (number of 0s is k) and then % 10
        // to get the last digit of the new number
        return (number / (int)Math.Pow(10, k-1)) % 10;
    }
```

However, there is an error message - "Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I think that Math.Pow returns double so it tries to convert the type of number to double. Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, `Math.Pow` returns `double`. So, you need to think about how to convert a `double` to an `int`... what have you tried? (And why are you assigning the result to `number` rather than just returning it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to integer?

```
static int GetDigit(int number, int k)
    {
        // k is the positiong of the digit I want to get from the number
        // I want to divide integer number to 10....0 (number of 0s is k) and then % 10
        // to get the last digit of the new number
        return (int)(number / Math.Pow(10, k)) % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah , it works that way , even though I put the (int) right before Math.Pow and it still works. Thanks anyways :) Problem now is , it returns the digit but from right to left. For example GetDigit(521671, 1) it will return 1. Any ideas ?

Comment: @leppie that's a good point, I must've added it by mistake. I was going to do a tostring on it but then decided against it and ended  up leaving it.